# Regarding mongodb query

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I have one document where the `awards` field is defined as follows:

```
"awards" : 
{

    "oscars" : [
        {"award": "bestAnimatedFeature", "result": "won"},
        {"award": "bestMusic", "result": "won"},
        {"award": "bestPicture", "result": "nominated"},
        {"award": "bestSoundEditing", "result": "nominated"},
        {"award": "bestScreenplay", "result": "nominated"}
    ],
    "wins" : 56,
    "nominations" : 86,
    "text" : "Won 2 Oscars. Another 56 wins and 86 nominations."
    }
```

I want the query document would we use in a find() command to return all movies in this collection that either won or were nominated for best picture?
Basically i want to count where the 'award' inside 'oscars' array is equal to "bestPicture".

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand but it's fairly trivial:

```
db.awards.find({"awards.oscars.award" : "bestPicture"},
{_id:1,"awards.text":1})
```

The second part is to display only Id and title of the movie.